# Quickly pruning elements in one structured array that exist in a separate unordered array

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists, which we'll call `testList` and `modifiedTestList`.  The first list looks something like this:

```
testList = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {RandomInteger[{0, 32}], 2}], {i, 1, 10}];
```

To generate `modifiedTestList`, I can flatten `testList` by strictly one level (never breaking up the pairs of real numbers specifying 2D coordinates), scramble the elements, and select and prune elements.  For example:

```
modifiedTestList = Flatten[testList, 1];
modifiedTestList = RandomSample[modifiedTestList, Length[modifiedTestList]];
modifiedTestList = Select[modifiedTestList, #[[1]] > 700 &];
```

Once I've had my fun, I'd like to take `testList` and prune away all of the 2D coordinates that no longer exist in `modifiedTestList` while respecting the original array structure of `testList` (i.e. `testList` should not be flattened and elements should not be moved between subarrays).

Let's say `testList` and `modifiedTestList` are both quite large ($>10^6$ elements each).  Is there a fast way to do the above pruning provided these large data structures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This method assumes `modifiedTestList` is a given.

```
rules = Dispatch@Thread[Rule[modifiedTestList, Sequence[]]]
tmp1=Replace[testList, rules, {2}]
```

Also

```
tmp2=DeleteCases[testList, Alternatives @@ modifiedTestList, {2}]
```

I've limited these to looking at level 2 so as to eliminate any unneeded level snooping. I'm sure others will have some alternatives but best to try on your real world example and report back the timings.

```
tmp1==tmp2
(*  True *)
```

**Edit**

I may have misread. In the above I've deleted the elements of `modifiedTestList` from `testList`. If you want the opposite then

```
tmp3=DeleteCases[testList, Except[Alternatives @@ modifiedTestList], {2}]
```

or

```
rules2 = Dispatch@Thread[Rule[Complement[Flatten[testList, 1], modifiedTestList], 
    Sequence[]]]
tmp4 = Replace[testList, rules2, {2}]

tmp3==tmp4
(*  True  *)
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, but thanks for your answer!

Comment: +1. You're right, I've deleted mine since it's very similar.

Comment: @RunnyKine changing `modifiedTestList` is also a possibility but I took it as a given for the purposes of answering the question.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch. Your answer is excellent. If I think up something really different I'll post. You already have my vote.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch By the way, thanks for your edit, I could have worked around it, but this latter section correctly interprets my question.

Answer (score 1):

Here are fresh-kernel times (on a slower machine) for `tmp4`, `tmp5`, and three more methods. `tmp6` is just `tmp5` using `Scan` instead of `Do`. `tmp7` and `tmp8` get the `Intersection` of the modified list with each original sublist; the results are sorted within sublists. `tmp8` saves time by reducing the modified list from one comparison to the next.

```
In[1]:= Length /@ (A = Table[RandomReal[{0, 1000}, {RandomInteger[{1*^4, 5*^4}], 2}], {10}])
Out[1]= {42008, 46556, 23970, 45599, 12340, 32636, 45232, 39218, 24238, 14579}

In[2]:= Length[B = RandomSample@Select[Join @@ A, #[[1]] > 700 &]]
Out[2]= 97983

In[3]:= First@AbsoluteTiming[
        rules2 = Dispatch@Thread[Rule[Complement[Flatten[A, 1], B], Sequence[]]];
        tmp4 = Replace[A, rules2, {2}];]
Out[3]= 6.239390

In[4]:= First@AbsoluteTiming[tmp5 = Block[{f}, Do[f[p] = p, {p, B}];
        f[_] := Sequence[]; Map[f, A, {2}]];]
Out[4]= 6.078836

In[5]:= First@AbsoluteTiming[tmp6 = Block[{f}, Scan[(f@# = #)&, B];
        f[_] := Sequence[]; Map[f, A, {2}]];]
Out[5]= 4.580439

In[6]:= SameQ[tmp4, tmp5, tmp6]
Out[6]= True

In[7]:= First@AbsoluteTiming[tmp7 = Intersection[#, B]& /@ A;]
Out[7]= 2.802139

In[8]:= First@AbsoluteTiming[tmp8 = Block[{b = B}, Join[
        ((b = Complement[b, #]; #)& @ Intersection[#, b])& /@ Most@A, {b}] ]]
Out[8]= 1.288282

In[9]:= SameQ[Sort/@tmp6, tmp7, tmp8]
Out[9]= True
```

Comment: It appears that `tmp7` and `tmp8` do not return the same as `tmp6` if `A` contains duplicates -- if a pair should remain, then its duplicates should remain, too.  (I changed `RandomReal` to `RandomInteger` to check.)

Comment: `tmp7` and `tmp8` are meant for situations in which the probability of any duplicates is negligible, as would be the case with RandomReal data.

Comment: Well, this question doesn't seem to be attracting much interest, even from the OP, so perhaps it was a moot point anyway. +1 for `Scan`.